# How to put a application in fullscreen using shell command in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, command-line, fullscreen

I would like to ensure a application is running in fullscreen using a shell command (or script). I've seen some approaches that tell the application to execute a keyboard shortcut (`cmd`+`ctrl`+`f`) but that will toogle the fullscreen mode, not ensure.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an AppleScript that can do it. Pass `true` or `false` to switch mode. The script uses the value of `AXFullScreen` to determine whether the app is currently in full screen and will only switch if necessary.

> ```
> Toggle an application from full screen to non full screen (or the reverse).
> Parameters:
>   1: application name(ie, Chrome)
>   2: boolean (true/false).
>      When true ensure that the application is in full screen mode (if not, make it so)
>      When false ensure that the application is NOT in full screen mode (if not, make it so)
> ```

```
on run argv
  set theapp to item 1 of argv
    if item 2 of argv is "false"
    set toggleOnFull to true
    else
    set toggleOnFull to false
    end if

  tell application theapp
    activate
    delay 2
    (* 
      Initially from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215501/applescript-use-lion-fullscreen
    *)
    set isfullscreen to false
    tell application "System Events" to tell process theapp
      set isfullscreen to value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1
    end tell
    --display dialog "var " & isfullscreen

    if isfullscreen is toggleOnFull then
      tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using { command down, control down }
      delay 2
    end if
  end tell
end run
```

<sup>Source: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dsummersl/4175461/raw/36811eab78ca5e1a25fbd547a44b3d9c8d0d424d/makeFullScreen.applescript</sup>

Comment: Hi @george-garside, I've tried the script with no success. I'm on Maverick and I get this error: `makeFullScreen.applescript:787:792: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)` when running from CL `osascript ~/Desktop/makeFullScreen.applescript HipChat true`. I've added Chrome to the accessibility apps in the OSX settings, but I get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @dome You need to give osascript assistive access: run `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "INSERT or REPLACE INTO access VALUES('kTCCServiceAccessibility','/usr/bin/osascript',1,1,1,NULL)"`

Comment: Done that, I can see it adds the osascript in the pref panel, but after all I still get the same error: `osascript ~/Desktop/makeFullScreen.applescript HipChat true`
`/Users/am/Desktop/makeFullScreen.applescript:787:792: execution error: System Events got an error: osascript is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)`

Comment: If someone got this working I would mark it as correct, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. I must be missing something here :/